# Drag and drop file from OSX finder to PyQt4 application

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I've got an app view I'm putting together with PyQt4, and am implementing a drag and drop feature on a QWebView.

I've got drag and drop working, except that when I drop a folder or file, it gives me some sort of OSX temporary filename (see `/.file/id=6571367.6613253/`), instead of the actual name and location. I'm wondering, is there any way to extrapolate 
the real directory or filename with full system path, or worst case at least can I operate on this temporary locator?

I do see an actual .file file on the root directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

    class MainView(QWebView):

        def __init__(self):
            QWebView.__init__(self)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)
            self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        def _result_available(self, ok):
            frame = self.page().mainFrame()

        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()

        def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
            if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
                event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()

        def dropEvent(self, event):
            if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
                event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
                event.accept()
                for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                    print QUrl(url.path())
            else:
                event.ignore()
```

Comment: This is a Yosemite bug that Qt must work around. This bug happens also to native Cocoa applications. It was fixed in Qt 5.4.1, but hasn't been backported to Qt 4 yet :(

Comment: That makes sense. Thankfully you can use PyQt5 with Python 2.7, so I will give that a shot and try to install it all tomorrow! Thanks to both of you!

Comment: PyQt5 did the trick, thanks!